# Closure Compiler annotations in WebStorm 6, how to use Record Types?

Tags: javascript, annotations, anonymous-function, google-closure-compiler

The following function is ok:

```
/**
 * Test
 * @param {{ aRandomKey: string, anotherKey  }} data
 */
function test(data) {
    console.log(data.aRandomKey);
}
```

Here `data.aRandomKey` is recognised as valid parameter.

Now the problem is in the following:

```
/**
 * @param { string, function({{ pageId: string }} data) }
 */
socket.on('page:getSource', function (data) {
    //data = { pageId: id }
    console.log(data.pageId)
})
```

Here, `data.pageId` is unresolved.. and the `@param`syntax is also wrong.

Same goes for:

```
socket.on('page:getSource',
    /**
    * @param {{ pageId: string }} data
    */
    function (data) {
        //data = { pageId: id }
        console.log(data.pageId)
    }
)
```

So.. how do I deal with these situations?

Comment: a workaround is extracting the function and giving it a name.. but I would prefer not having to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example the annotation is incorrectly applying to `socket.on`, not to the callback function. In addition, the annotation is formatted incorrectly. An @param tag describes exactly one parameter and it's type. You are attempting to describe two. Also, record types only need one set of braces surrounding them.  Here's one way that might look:

```
/**
 * @param {string} eventName,
 * @param {function({ pageId: string })} callback
 */
socket.on = function(eventName, callback) {};

socket.on('page:getSource', function (data) {
    //data = { pageId: id }
    console.log(data.pageId)
});
```

Your second example seems correct - but since the `socket.on` definition wasn't provided I can't verify. Here's a similar test case that does work:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// @warning_level VERBOSE
// @formatting pretty_print
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

function test2(a, b) {
  b(a);
}

test2({pageId: 17},
    /**
     * @param {{ pageId: string }} data
     */
    function (data) {
        //data = { pageId: id }
        console.log(data.pageId)
    }
);
```

Comment: it is a problem of WebStorm, then, because your second example does not work there. it only works if I name the function, e.g. `/** @param {{ pageId: string }} data */ var f = function(data) { .. }` and `test2({pageId: 17}, f)`